# Automatic reply or dialog for "thanks, this solves my issue" comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, thanks, automation

I've stumbled upon many answers which had OP comments such as "thanks, this solves it" but OP forgot to accept (or possibly upvote) the answer.

I noted that if I flag such comments some of them are deleted immediately, so I think it's a script that autodetects that the message is just saying "thanks" and removes it (not a moderator).

Couldn't then a dialog with this informational message

> It looks like you are saying thanks to the writer of this answer. Consider instead simply voting and/or accepting the answer.

pop up whenever the script detects OP is trying to submit a thanks message?

This would save manual flagging by users and possibly give some points to users who otherwise might never get them if OP never comes back.

Comment: Sry just noted a same question in the sidebar and closed it myself. This may be deleted if useless.

Comment: This is probably one of those *good* duplicates for that feature request, so there's probably no need to delete it.

Comment: It could be. Or several users flagged the comment. From [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757) (my emphasis): *"Comments that are flagged by* ***multiple users*** *are deleted automatically. The number of flags needed is usually based on the comment's score. It currently takes "3 + (Score / 3)" flags (rounded up) to delete a comment. Comments containing* ***certain keywords*** *can be deleted with a* ***single*** *flag."*